# Predicting probabilities in a raster using SVM

Tags: raster, r

I trained a SVM (Support Vector Machine) model using `e1071` package as follows:

```
svm <- svm(class ~ ., data=train, type="C-classification", kernel="radial")
```

Now I am trying to predict the values and probabilities in a raster. Following the same approach as when I use `randomForest`. The following code correctly predicts the values:

```
r_pred <- raster::predict(model=svm, object=img)
```

However when using

```
r_prob <- raster::predict(model=svm, object=img, type="prob", index=1:length(unique(train[[1]])))
```

I get a RasterBrick with values from 1 to 3 (my labels) instead of 0 to 1 (probabilities).

```
> r_prob
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 11276, 8878, 100108328, 3  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent     : 744560, 753438, 4308462, 4319738  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=30 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : r_tmp_2021-11-22_125836_11220_94025.grd 
names      : layer.1, layer.2, layer.3 
min values :       1,       1,       1 
max values :       3,       3,       3
```

Any solution without having to convert the RasterStack of predictors to data.frame and vice versa?

Comment: Can you make a simple reproducible example with a built-in or toy dataset? I'm not sure why you are concerned about not converting the raster to a dataframe because I bet that's probably the first thing raster::predict does in order to call the underlying predict method for the model class...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using `predict.svm.probs()` function. This function performs the following steps: a) Converts the RasterStack containing the predictors as a data.frame. b) Get the prediction of probabilities using the above data.frame. c) Join the XY columns and the probabilities obtained. d) Convert the data.frame back to a RasterStack containing the georeferenced probabilities.

```
predict.svm.probs <- function(mdl, rst){
  # predict.svm arguments:
  # mdl: svm model fitted.
  # rst: raster stack with predictors. the name of the layers would be the same expected by the model.
  df <- as.data.frame(rst, xy=TRUE)
  df_pred <- predict(mdl, df[3:ncol(df)], probability=TRUE)
  df_prob <- attr(df_pred, "probabilities")
  df_prob <- cbind(df[1:2], df_prob)
  r_prob <- rasterFromXYZ(df_prob)
  projection(r_prob) <- projection(rst)
  return(r_prob)
}
```

To use the function:

```
# train svm model
svm <- svm(class ~., data=train, type="C-classification", kernel="radial", probability=TRUE)

# predict svm probabilities in a RasterStack
r <- predict.svm.probs(mdl=svm, rst=img)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to *at least* fit and predict the model with `probability=TRUE`. Without it:

```
> svm = svm(class ~ ., data=train, type="C-classification", kernel="radial")
> p = predict(svm, data.frame(x0=runif(100)), probability=TRUE)
Warning message:
In predict.svm(svm, data.frame(x0 = runif(100)), probability = TRUE) :
  SVM has not been trained using `probability = TRUE`, probabilities not available for predictions.
```

So no probs:

```
> str(p)
Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:100] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
```

Try with:

```
> svm = svm(class ~ ., data=train, type="C-classification", kernel="radial",probability=TRUE)
> p = predict(svm, data.frame(x0=runif(100)), probability=TRUE)
> str(p)
 Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:100] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 - attr(*, "probabilities")= num [1:100, 1:3] 0.414 0.409 0.39 0.389 0.412 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:100] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "B" "C" "A"
```

and there's probabilities.

Note this is all not with raster::predict but you'll need to make this work in plain data first.

It looks to me like `predict` returns the predicted class but with the probabilities as *attributes* which might mean feeding an svm to `raster::predict` even with probability calculation on won't work, so you'll have to resort to predicting using the raster values as a data frame and then building an output raster from the probability attribute of the predict method on that data frame.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer helped me find a solution by following these steps: Convert raster to dataframe using `as.data.frame(xy = TRUE)`. Then make the prediction and get the probabilities. Then match the XY coordinates with the probabilities. Finally convert the data.frame to RasterStack using the `rasterFromXYZ()` function.